# PHP log into remote site and download csv

Tags: php

I need to create a php script that logs into remote site then downloads a csv file on that site.  I've searched all over and haven't found anything that does what I need. Currently I only have the following code which allows me to login to a remote site.

```
<?php
$username=""; 
$password=""; 
$url=''; 
$cookie=""; 
$postdata = 'email='.$username.'&pass='.$password; 

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US;       rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true); 
$result = curl_exec($ch); 
echo $result;  
curl_close($ch);
```

?>

Comment: have you tried using exec() command?

Comment: Depends on how you need to determine which csv file to download. Do you know the URL beforehand? Or does it change each time you log in?

Comment: @Stobor I know the url before hand it never changes.

Comment: Why do you have to do it with PHP?  To avoid reinventing the wheel, how about using `wget` or tcl/expect?

Comment: @Stobor thanks for responding so quickly.  Its still not working.  Could it be because the csv file is not located on the landing page after login?

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:

```
<?php
$username=""; 
$password=""; 
$url=''; 
$csvurl=''; 
$cookie=""; 
$postdata = 'email='.$username.'&pass='.$password; 

/*first log in*/
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US;       rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true); 
$result = curl_exec($ch); 
echo $result;  

/*now download the file*/
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $csvurl); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
$result = curl_exec($ch); 
echo $result;  


curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Comment: thanks @Stobor.. it doesn't seem to work though.. would it be because after the login occurs the csv link isn't located on the landing page. Would it need to redirect to the page where the csv link is located?

Comment: Depends on what the site does between login and csv download. Note that my code already assumes that the login url and csv url are different. Any more detail requires more information about the site, or what isn't working.